# So is there any C++ alternative for PiUi?

Tags: python, usb, android, c++

So actually I have a little project that require the Pi to communicate to a Smartphone (in this case android device) to transact data (sending and receiving command, etc) via any available connection (in this case I choose USB) using my very own written application.

Then I found [PiUi](http://blog.davidsingleton.org/introducing-piui/) which is I see good for my project, but it's written in Python and I need the one that written in C++ since my current programming language is C++ and I know nothing bout Python

So the point is I need a API, Libary, etc that could interfacing between Pi and Android device and it's written in C++. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

So people,not best answer though but this could help for those who have problem with me.

Try use [gnublin](http://en.gnublin.org/index.php/Main_Page) API.Haven't do a deep research yet but seems considerable (it's also compactible with Python)

but for those who still want to give me reccomendation,i'll wating for it.